# How to take value as value without considering it as string when we do cat and grep

Tags: bash, environment-variables, grep, cat

I have created the utility that need to be run in all the system without any error by creating the required environment. When ever I run the following command it will take the path value from a config file and that should assign that value into BASE_DIR variable

```
export BASE_DIR=`cat <config file path> | grep BASE_DIR | head -1 | cut -d = -f 2`
```

Following is the content of config file:

```
BASE_DIR=$HOME/flshrc
```

when I run the first code it is taking value as `$HOME/flshrc` instead of the actual home path, for example `/home/user1/flshrc`

How to not consider the grepped value as string and should be considered as the actual value and substitute the $HOME value?

Thank you.

Comment: can't you just run `source <config file path>` ?

Comment: Yeah, I see you're `cat`-ing the contents of the file but the shell is not processing that line. So you could do `$(cat yourfile.conf)` to get it to process. Are you after `basename $(echo $HOME)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `envsubst` utility. For example, given the following `configfile`

```
foo=bar
BASE_DIR=$HOME/flshrc
USER=$USER
```

then

```
$ envsubst < configfile | awk -F= '$1 == "BASE_DIR" {print $2}'
/home/steeldriver/flshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider a different method to provide configuration to your script:

**config**:

```
foo=bar
export BASE_DIR=$HOME/flshrc
```

**main**:

```
source config
echo "$BASE_DIR"
```

---

> [**source filename [arguments]**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) - Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell environment

---

You probably should add the [path to the main script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within) to the `source` command, otherwise the `config` file is searched for in the current directory:

**main**:

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )"
source "$SCRIPT_DIR/config"
echo "$BASE_DIR"
```